# Reference to type-erased void*

Tags: c++, casting, reference, lvalue

I'm implementing an iterator adaptor that allows to deal with an old data type saving `void*`, and I would like to get a `forward_iterator` that allows to swap values of that old data type, by giving the user a view of the real pointer that is saved in that structure. Example:

```
auto it = iterator_adaptor<T*>(pos);
```

where `pos->object` is a `void*` that was originally of type `T*`. The thing is about the reference type:

```
// within iterator_adaptor
typedef T*& reference;

// I want to promise that to the user.
typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category; 

reference operator*() const { return static_cast<reference>(_pos->object); }
```

Which yields a compiler error since I cannot wrap a reference over an object of a distinct type. I could cast between references, or between pointers, if types are related, but how could I cast a `void*` lvalue to a `T*&` in a non-undefined behaviour way, knowing that `_pos->object` points to an object of type `T`?

The only thing that I can think of that might be swallow by the compiler is:

```
return *reinterpret_cast<T**>(&_pos->object);
```

or something in this direction, but that must be defined as undefined behaviour by the standard with 100% probability.

**NOTE**: I would like to return a `T*&`, not a `T&`, since some semantics of each `T` are defined by its address (specifically, there's hash tables that maps `T::id()` to its address, since each `T::id()` is unique per `T*`). If I return `T&` and the user swaps them, address and `id` doesn't match anymore, to give some example that might broke the application. I want rather to allow the user to swap the positions of each `T*` within the structure (because the user saves pointers after all; each `T` is created dynamically before inserting into the structure), to personalize its ordering for example, or use any `std` algorithm requiring both, forward and input iterators.

Actually, the "swap" positions thing is not so important, but using the `<algorithm>` library for algorithms requiring forward iterators is a feature I would like to offer.

Comment: I'm going the other direction. I'm revisiting my old C code interfaces to make them as typed as possible. Let no `void*` live....

Comment: You might return a wrapper instead of a real reference: `typedef my_ref_wrapper<T*> reference;`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm actually doing what you say. I'm trying to type everything again.

Comment: @Jarod42 That won't yield a ForwardIterator.

Comment: `typedef struct { void* ptr_ } A;` works ... and is type checked even in C. @Peregring-lk Great! It helped me a good deal.

Comment: Personally I would make the iterator return a `T&` instead of a `T*&`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek It doesn't follow the habits of the project. Besides, the "`value_type`" of the old structure is `T*`, not `T` (the node `*pos` contains a pointer, not the object itself).

Comment: A, ahem, C-style cast seems to work, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QAwlctvkjICUZouo

Comment: @PaulSanders I would say that's undefined behaviour as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let me get this straight (a mcve would have helped so much):

You have this situation:

```
X x1{}, x2;
X* p = &x1;

void* vp = reinterpret_cast<void*>(p);

// p is lost

// here you want to recover p such that:
X*& q = /* something magic from vp */;
q = &x2; // this will modify p
```

If this is the case that is simply impossible because you lost the object `p` forever. You saved in `vp` to what `p` pointed, a.k.a you saved its value, aka you saved the address of `x1` (in a type erased way) and that is recoverable, the pointee is recoverable (if you know the original type), but `p` is lost, it was never saved.

---

If you want to recover `p` then you need to save it's address:

```
X x1{11}, x2{27};
X* p = &x1;

void* vpp = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&p);

// p must not end lifetime !! very important

X*& q = *reinterpret_cast<X**>(vpp);
q = &x2; // will indeed modify p (p must still be alive)
```

---

Otherwise you can do this, it's perfectly valid:

```
T& a = *reinterpret_cast<T*>(pos->object);
T* p = reinterpret_cast<T*>(pos->object);
```

---

And finally some standard dessert (emphasis mine):

> §8.5.1.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]
>
> 7. An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. <sup>73</sup> When a prvalue v of object pointer
>      type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the
>      result is `static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`. [ Note:
>      **Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to
>      T2”** (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment
>      requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) **and back to its
>      original type yields the original pointer value**. — end note ]

In the simplest example:

```
X* p = /* ... */;

void* v = reinterpret_cast<void*>(p);

X* q = reinterpret_cast<X*>(v);

// q is guaranteed to have the original value of p,
// i.e. p == q is true
```